# Laravel listener not working - what is missing?

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel V7

The event (which is working)

```
class IssueUpdated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $issue;
    public $oldIssue;
    public $user;

    public function __construct($issue, $oldIssue, $user)
    {
        $this->issue = $issue;
        $this->oldIssue = $oldIssue;
        $this->user = $user;
        Log::info('Test event');
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

I can find the log in `laravel.log` -> it works

Listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\Notification;

use App\Events\Issue\IssueUpdated;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class ChangeIssueAssigneeListener
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        Log::info('Test listener');
    }

    public function handle(IssueUpdated $event)
    {
        //
    }
```

No log on `laravel.log` from the listener.

EventServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Events\Issue\IssueUpdated;
use App\Listeners\Notification\ChangeIssueAssigneeListener;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;


class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],

        IssueUpdated::class => [
            ChangeIssueAssigneeListener::class
        ]
    ];
    
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        //
    }
}
```

I ran the following commands:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: i think your ChangeIssueAssigneeListener missing `handle` method.. `handle(IssueUpdated $event)`.. refer here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#defining-listeners

Comment: The handle method is there. I cuted theme because to much code in stackoverflow.

Comment:  its look right.. have you try to restart artisan and serve again?

Comment: I added the commands i did in my question

Comment: For a test,  i changed the class name from the listener from `class ChangeIssueAssigneeListener` to `class ChangeIssueAssig` there is no error message or log message. Looks like the class is not called....

Comment: i tested your code.. its working fine.. able to log it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222593/discussion-between-peter-and-zeroone).

Comment: are you aliasing the event and listener in that service provider correctly? and what is firing this event

Comment: @lagbox above you can see the EventServiceProvider. I call the event in the controller `        new IssueUpdated($issue, $request->user());` The log message from the event appears in `laravel.log` but no the message from the listener

Comment: just creating a new event object does not "dispatch"/"fire" it ... and I can't see the import/alias you are using in that service provider

Comment: I added the full EventServiceProvider

Comment: you have to actually dispatch the event that you created

Comment: You saved my life. Instead of        `event(new IssueUpdated($issue, $request->user()));` I wrote `new IssueUpdated($issue, $request->user())`

Answer (score 0):

Please attempt after execute following command

```
 php artisan queue:work
```

then maybe it will work